# Writing unicode to a file in ascii in python (for example as u'\xa0EC)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, file-writing

I've written a simple script in python that scrapes a website for some data and saves it into a list called data. Some of the data has unicode characters, I want to write this list to a .csv file and keep the unicode characters in ascii.

When I print the list in the python shell the unicode characters show up as, for example "u'\xa0EC" and I just want them saved exactly like that in the .csv so that they can be interpreted later back into unicode/utf-8.

I'm sure this can't be that difficult but I'm either getting the "ascii codec can't encode..." error or what I have at the moment replaces them with question marks -

```
f = codecs.open('data2.csv', mode='wb', encoding="ascii",  errors='ignore')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow([i.encode('ascii','replace') if type(i) is unicode else i for i in data])
f.close()
```

Apologies if this has be answered before, I have searched, but every other question seems to be people wanting them converted.

Comment: Instead of encoding to ascii (which means loss of data), why not encode it to utf-8 ?

Comment: The output will be uploaded to a sever where it's going to be interpreted into UTF-8 but it needs to be in ascii to be uploaded.

Comment: have you considered using html escapes such as `u'\xa0EC'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace') == b'&#160;EC'`
if the field content *is* html. Or just dump the whole list as json: `json.dumps([u'\xa0EC']) == '["\\u00a0EC"]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the "unicode_escape" encoding.
For example:

```
s = "雥"
s.encode("unicode_escape")
```

yields the following bytes:

```
b'\\u96e5'
```

To get the ascii representation, you would want to decode the bytes with the ascii encoding as such:

```
s.encode("unicode_escape").decode('ascii')
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to have worked perfectly. As a further question is there a way to easily encode them in decimal representaton?

Comment: @JimmyBoom try using the `ord` function, eg. `ord('雥')`

Comment: @JimmyBoom: don't use `unicode_escape` as a serialization format, there are more portable standard [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493357/writing-unicode-to-a-file-in-ascii-in-python-for-example-as-u-xa0ec#comment50954320_31493357)